# Closed formula for $\sum\limits^\infty_{k=0}\frac1{(k+a)(k+b)} L^1_k(x)L^1_k(y) $

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials, hermite-polynomials, laguerre

Let $ L^{\alpha}_{n}(x)=\sum^{n}_{k=0} \binom{n+\alpha}{n-k}\big(-1\big)^{k}\frac{x^{k}}{k!},\alpha>-1$ be Laguerre polynomials of type $ n$.
Is there a closed formula for $$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{1}{(k+a)(k+b)} L^{1}_{k}(x)L^{1}_{k}(y) $$
Thank you

Comment: even the simpler case $x=y$, $a=b$ does not seem to have a closed-form answer

Comment: I think there is a formula when $a=b=1$.